# Vue update state after router push

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my application I have a page with params I'd like to redirect the user to a 'destination' page after they login. I can do a `$router.push` like this:

```
this.$router.push({
   name: "foo",
   params: {
      title: "Hello",
      message: "World!"
   }
});
```

The user has just been logged in programatically at this point and I'd like the state of the root component to update so that, for example, the "Logout" button appears. I can refresh the page with `this.$router.go()` but then I'd need some logic to prevent infinite refreshes. I don't want to refresh from the 'destination' page because it's a component I use elsewhere. I don't think I can reload the window to that destination because I need to pass params.

Is there a way I can `$router.push()` with a reload, or refresh the `App.vue` component state without a reload?

Comment: State is reactive, all you have to do is mutate it. Your logic should go... 1) Login, 2) Set authenticated state, 3) Router push to new destination

Comment: What Phil said.
If you're using some state management with Vuex, Pinia or whatever it should be reactive i.e, when a user logs in you set his loggedIn state to true and that mutation should trigger a change in any component that uses the value to render or compute something.

Comment: I have a $store which updates the token in the state, then a getter in the $store which checks there is a token in the state. In the component I render based on the $store getter. I am guessing the last part is where the problem is.